# How do I combine text and numerical features in training set for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, ipython, svm, feature-selection

I am trying to predict the number of likes on a post in a social network basing on both on numerical features and text features. Now I have dataframe with required features, but I don't know what to do with posts text data. Should I vectorize it/do smth else in order to get a suitable train matrix? I am going to use LinearSVC from sklearn for analysis.

[image: my dataframe looks this way]

Comment: What macnine learning method are you planning to use?  SVMs might be a good choice since you are dealing with textual features.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't mentioned, yes, I am going to use SVM. Linear SVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways you can transform your text features into numerical ones.

One of the most common ways is the Bag of Words approach. Where you transform your text into an array with the occurrences of each word.

If you are using scikit-learn I recommend you reading their [Text Feature extraction User Guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).

Also look at the [NLTK toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/) for more complex ways to process your text data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand, that I need a Bug of Words. I've already divided posts' text data into words and conducted preprocessing. I have no idea what to do next, how to join it into one matrix for future SVM analysis.

Comment: Got your idea and found dull mistakes in my code. Thank you for your answer:)